# LiveWallpaper, реагирующий на касания

Tags: livewallpaper, android, java

В ОС Android вообще можно реализовать LiveWallaper, реагирующий на касания экрана? По идее, метод public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) для переопределения у него есть. Написал простенькую заготовку. Никакой реакции на касания. Метод просто не выполняется. Приведу свой класс-наследник LiveWallpaper'а:

```
package com.topsher.indicator;

import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class IndicatorBlocksWallpaper extends WallpaperService {

private Rect surf;
private Painter mPainter;
private String TAG = "IndicatorBlockWallpaper";
@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new MyEngine();
}

class MyEngine extends Engine
{
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        holder.getSurfaceFrame();
        super.onSurfaceCreated(holder); 
        mPainter = new Painter(holder, getApplicationContext());
        mPainter.start();
        //mPainter.drawIndicator();
        // mPainter.runMotion();
        //mPainter.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
                    //..
        Log.d(TAG, "new Touch Event!");
        //..
    }

}
```

}

В логе события просто никак не регистрируется. Установленная в эмуляторе обоина просто висит фоном, но не реагирует на события. Подскажите возможные упущения или нет вообще таковой возможности как реагировать на разные события "Живым Обоям"?

Comment: я думаю, что сама возможность точно есть, так как, по крайней мере, на моем нексусе есть две "живые обоины", которые реагируют на нажатие пальцем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вся проблема похоже в свойстве [setTouchEventsEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/wallpaper/WallpaperService.Engine.html#setTouchEventsEnabled(boolean)), которое по умолчанию false :-).

Comment: Да, спасибо. Разбирал пример, но упустил этот момент..

Answer (score 1):

Такое конечно же возможно. Сам не разбирался, но нагуглил вот это:
[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298458/android-live-wallpaper-touch-event-hierarchy)

Добавлю парочку моментов:

1. Для реализации обоин можно использовать плагин к игровому движку AndEngine. Получается гораздо меньше кода.
2. Посмотрите пример обоины в доке:
   [Тыц](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/live-wallpapers.html)